# SPSS string field to numeric conversion

Tags: spss

I have a field in my data with `low, middle and high`. I want to replace `low` with 1, `middle` with 2 and `high` with 3.

Is there a good way to do this?

(I'm very Beginner for SPSS software.)

Answer (score 1):

Else you could simply write this as Syntax:

```
string new_variable (a1).
RECODE
  old_variable
  ("low"="1") ("middle"="2") ("high"="3") INTO new_variable.
EXECUTE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a link which solve my problem and sharing for others, who came accross for same problem.
http://www.unige.ch/ses/sococ/cl/spss/tasks/createdummies.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're measuring you could consider to type the field as a ordinal value type. It is not technically an interval value.

Answer (score 0):

```
if oldString="low" newNum=1.
if oldString="middle" newNum=2.
if oldString="high" newNum=3.
```